# Is it possible to override document.cookie in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, cookies, webkit

In Firefox it's possible using the following...

```
HTMLDocument.prototype.__defineGetter__("cookie",function (){return "foo=bar";});
HTMLDocument.prototype.__defineSetter__("cookie",function (){});
```

This doesn't cause any errors in WebKit, and WebKit definitely supports `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`, but it doesn't work. Guessing WebKit is protecting that property somehow.

So, any ideas of how to achieve the same effect in WebKit?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried do define the getter/setter pair on the document object itself, instead on the prototype?

```
document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function() {} );
document.__defineSetter__("cookie", function() {} );
```

I know it shouldn't matter, but I don't underestimate browser quirks. Even with WebKit.

#### Update

I've done some tests in Chrome 2 and it appears that it only allows defining a setter. Anyway, I'm not sure how valid this observation is to WebKit, as Google Chrome uses a different JavaScript interpreter than WebKit.

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately that also doesn't work in Safari (neither getter or setter).